# How to specific the path url for image in css file

Tags: python, django

I have a file css have code like this:

```
background-image: url("../img/mega-menu/corner_image.jpg");
```

How can I specific the path of image in folder static/img. I can not use

```
{% load staticfiles %} and {% url %}
```

in file css

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full path

```
background-image: url("/whatever_the_static_url_is/img/mega-menu/corner_image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel-body {
    background-image : url("/static/Images/add.png") !important ;
    position: absolute;  /* optional */
}
```